# Quicksort Algorithm Speed

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, sorting, quick-sort

I have made a sorting algorithm in Python 3. This sorting algorithm is a modified optimized *median of 3 quicksort*, with *network sorting* for lists of size up to 16 and for finding the median. I have tried using the O(N) approach to finding the median, but sorting normally was faster.
Can I get some advice on how to make this faster?
Also, can anyone link fast sorting algorithms? I want to compare them to mine and see if there are faster, and if they are, how I can improve mine. The first like 1000 lines is the network sorting (I made a program to automatically generate code for the network sorting, I am not a madman), and the final 20ish is testing how fast it is. On my laptop, it sorts 100,000 random numbers in about **0.192** seconds and 1,000,000 random numbers in about **2.754** seconds. (Note that python's time is not 100% accurate. I used multiple tests and found the average.)

I have compared my code to mergesort, heapsort, other quicksorts, timsort, and radix sort, but none of them seem to be close to beating my code. However, that is likely because they were from how-to sites, and were not optimized. Sadly, most people who care about having a quick sorting algorithm seem to write it in Java, C or C++ which I can't really compare.   So, I would appreciate any other optimized sorting algorithms, or even suggestions to my original code.

```
#importing

import math
import random
import time

#this is the sorting network (scroll a bunch, this is like 1000 lines)

def sorting_network(lst):
    l = len(lst)

    if l < 9:
        if l < 5:
            if l < 3:
                if not l or l == 1:
                    return lst
                else:
                    a = lst[0]
                    b = lst[1]
                    
                    if a > b:
                        a, b = b, a
                    
                    return [a, b]
            else:
                if l == 3:
                    a = lst[0]
                    b = lst[1]
                    c = lst[2]
                    
                    if a > b:
                        a, b = b, a
                    if b > c:
                        b, c = c, b
                    if a > b:
                        a, b = b, a

                    return [a, b, c]

                else:
                    a = lst[0]
                    b = lst[1]
                    c = lst[2]
                    d = lst[3]
                    
                    if a > b:
                        a, b = b, a
                    if c > d:
                        c, d = d, c
                    if a > c:
                        a, c = c, a
                    if b > d:
                        b, d = d, b
                    if b > c:
                        b, c = c, b

                    return [a, b, c, d]

        else:
            if l < 7:
                if l == 5:
                    a = lst[0]
                    b = lst[1]
                    c = lst[2]
                    d = lst[3]
                    e = lst[4]
                    
                    if a > d:
                        a, d = d, a
                    if b > e:
                        b, e = e, b
                    if a > b:
                        a, b = b, a
                    if c > e:
                        c, e = e, c
                    if b > c:
                        b, c = c, b
                    if d > e:
                        d, e = e, d
                    if c > d:
                        c, d = d, c

                    return [a, b, c, d, e]
                else:
                    a = lst[0]
                    b = lst[1]
                    c = lst[2]
                    d = lst[3]
                    e = lst[4]
                    f = lst[5]
                    
                    if a > f:
                        a, f = f, a
                    if b > d:
                        b, d = d, b
                    if c > e:
                        c, e = e, c
                    if b > c:
                        b, c = c, b
                    if d > e:
                        d, e = e, d
                    if a > d:
                        a, d = d, a
                    if c > f:
                        c, f = f, c
                    if a > b:
                        a, b = b, a
                    if c > d:
                        c, d = d, c
                    if e > f:
                        e, f = f, e
                    if b > c:
                        b, c = c, b
                    if d > e:
                        d, e = e, d

                    return [a, b, c, d, e, f]
            else:
                if l == 7:
                    a = lst[0]
                    b = lst[1]
                    c = lst[2]
                    d = lst[3]
                    e = lst[4]
                    f = lst[5]
                    g = lst[6]
                    
                    if a > b:
                        a, b = a, b
                    if c > d:
                        c, d = d, c
                    if e > f:
                        e, f = f, e
                    if a > c:
                        a, c = c, a
                    if b > e:
                        b, e = e, b
                    if d > g:
                        d, g = g, d
                    if a > b:
                        a, b = b, a
                    if c > f:
                        c, f = f, c
                    if d > e:
                        d, e = e, d
                    if b > c:
                        b, c = c, b
                    if e > g:
                        e, g = g, e
                    if c > d:
                        c, d = d, c
                    if e > f:
                        e, f = f, e
                    if b > c:
                        b, c = c, b
                    if d > e:
                        d, e = e, d
                    if f > g:
                        f, g = g, f
                    
                    return [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
                else:
                    a = lst[0]
                    b = lst[1]
                    c = lst[2]
                    d = lst[3]
                    e = lst[4]
                    f = lst[5]
                    g = lst[6]
                    h = lst[7]
                    
                    if a > c:
                        a, c = c, a
                    if b > d:
                        b, d = d, b
                    if e > g:
                        e, g = g, e
                    if f > h:
                        f, h = h, f
                    if a > e:
                        a, e = e, a
                    if b > f:
                        b, f = f, b
                    if c > g:
                        c, g = g, c
                    if d > h:
                        d, h = h, d
                    if a > b:
                        a, b = b, a
                    if c > d:
                        c, d = d, c
                    if e > f:
                        e, f = f, e
                    if g > h:
                        g, h = h, g
                    if c > e:
                        c, e = e, c
                    if d > f:
                        d, f = f, d
                    if b > e:
                        b, e = e, b
                    if d > g:
                        d, g = g, d
                    if b > c:
                        b, c = c, b
                    if d > e:
                        d, e = e, d
                    if f > g:
                        f, g = g, f

                    return [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]

    else:
        if l < 13:
            if l < 11:
                if l == 9:
                    a = lst[0]
                    b = lst[1]
                    c = lst[2]
                    d = lst[3]
                    e = lst[4]
                    f = lst[5]
                    g = lst[6]
                    h = lst[7]
                    i = lst[8]
                    
                    if a > d:
                        a, d = d, a
                    if b > h:
                        b, h = h, b
                    if c > f:
                        c, f = f, c
                    if e > i:
                        e, i = i, e
                    if a > h:
                        a, h = h, a
                    if c > e:
                        c, e = e, c
                    if d > i:
                        d, i = i, d
                    if f > g:
                        f, g = g, f
                    if a > c:
                        a, c = c, a
                    if b > d:
                        b, d = d, b
                    if e > f:
                        e, f = f, e
                    if h > i:
                        h, i = i, h
                    if b > e:
                        b, e = e, b
                    if d > g:
                        d, g = g, d
                    if f > h:
                        f, h = h, f
                    if a > b:
                        a, b = b, a
                    if c > e:
                        c, e = e, c
                    if d > f:
                        d, f = f, d
                    if g > i:
                        g, i = i, g
                    if c > d:
                        c, d = d, c
                    if e > f:
                        e, f = f, e
                    if g > h:
                        g, h = h, g
                    if b > c:
                        b, c = c, b
                    if d > e:
                        d, e = e, d
                    if f > g:
                        f, g = g, f

                    return [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i]

                else:
                    a = lst[0]
                    b = lst[1]
                    c = lst[2]
                    d = lst[3]
                    e = lst[4]
                    f = lst[5]
                    g = lst[6]
                    h = lst[7]
                    i = lst[8]
                    j = lst[9]
                    
                    if a > i:
                        a, i = i, a
                    if b > j:
                        b, j = j, b
                    if c > h:
                        c, h = h, c
                    if d > f:
                        d, f = f, d
                    if e > g:
                        e, g = g, e
                    if a > c:
                        a, c = c, a
                    if b > e:
                        b, e = e, b
                    if f > i:
                        f, i = i, f
                    if h > j:
                        h, j = j, h
                    if a > d:
                        a, d = d, a
                    if c > e:
                        c, e = e, c
                    if f > h:
                        f, h = h, f
                    if g > j:
                        g, j = j, g
                    if a > b:
                        a, b = b, a
                    if d > g:
                        d, g = g, d
                    if i > j:
                        i, j = j, i
                    if b > f:
                        b, f = f, b
                    if c > d:
                        c, d = d, c
                    if e > i:
                        e, i = i, e
                    if g > h:
                        g, h = h, g
                    if b > c:
                        b, c = c, b
                    if d > f:
                        d, f = f, d
                    if e > g:
                        e, g = g, e
                    if h > i:
                        h, i = i, h
                    if c > d:
                        c, d = d, c
                    if e > f:
                        e, f = f, e
                    if g > h:
                        g, h = h, g
                    if d > e:
                        d, e = e, d
                    if f > g:
                        f, g = g, f

                    return [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j]

            else:
                if l == 11:
                    a = lst[0]
                    b = lst[1]
                    c = lst[2]
                    d = lst[3]
                    e = lst[4]
                    f = lst[5]
                    g = lst[6]
                    h = lst[7]
                    i = lst[8]
                    j = lst[9]
                    k = lst[10]

                    if b > g:
                        b, g = g, b
                    if c > e:
                        c, e = e, c
                    if d > h:
                        d, h = h, d
                    if f > i:
                        f, i = i, f
                    if a > b:
                        a, b = b, a
                    if d > f:
                        d, f = f, d
                    if e > k:
                        e, k = k, e
                    if g > j:
                        g, j = j, g
                    if h > i:
                        h, i = i, h
                    if b > d:
                        b, d = d, b
                    if c > f:
                        c, f = f, c
                    if e > h:
                        e, h = h, e
                    if i > k:
                        i, k = k, i
                    if a > e:
                        a, e = e, a
                    if b > c:
                        b, c = c, b
                    if d > h:
                        d, h = h, d
                    if f > j:
                        f, j = j, f
                    if g > i:
                        g, i = i, g
                    if a > b:
                        a, b = b, a
                    if c > g:
                        c, g = g, c
                    if e > f:
                        e, f = f, e
                    if h > i:
                        h, i = i, h
                    if j > k:
                        j, k = k, j
                    if c > e:
                        c, e = e, c
                    if d > g:
                        d, g = g, d
                    if f > h:
                        f, h = h, f
                    if i > j:
                        i, j = j, i
                    if b > c:
                        b, c = c, b
                    if d > e:
                        d, e = e, d
                    if f > g:
                        f, g = g, f
                    if h > i:
                        h, i = i, h
                    if c > d:
                        c, d = d, c
                    if e > f:
                        e, f = f, e
                    if g > h:
                        g, h = h, g

                    return [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k]

                else:
                    a = lst[0]
                    b = lst[1]
                    c = lst[2]
                    d = lst[3]
                    e = lst[4]
                    f = lst[5]
                    g = lst[6]
                    h = lst[7]
                    i = lst[8]
                    j = lst[9]
                    k = lst[10]
                    l = lst[11]
                    
                    if b > h:
                        b, h = h, b
                    if c > g:
                        c, g = g, c
                    if d > l:
                        d, l = l, d
                    if e > k:
                        e, k = k, e
                    if f > j:
                        f, j = j, f
                    if a > b:
                        a, b = b, a
                    if c > f:
                        c, f = f, c
                    if d > e:
                        d, e = e, d
                    if g > j:
                        g, j = j, g
                    if h > i:
                        h, i = i, h
                    if k > l:
                        k, l = l, k
                    if a > c:
                        a, c = c, a
                    if b > g:
                        b, g = g, b
                    if f > k:
                        f, k = k, f
                    if j > l:
                        j, l = l, j
                    if a > d:
                        a, d = d, a
                    if b > c:
                        b, c = c, b
                    if e > g:
                        e, g = g, e
                    if f > h:
                        f, h = h, f
                    if i > l:
                        i, l = l, i
                    if j > k:
                        j, k = k, j
                    if b > e:
                        b, e = e, b
                    if d > f:
                        d, f = f, d
                    if g > i:
                        g, i = i, g
                    if h > k:
                        h, k = k, h
                    if b > d:
                        b, d = d, b
                    if c > f:
                        c, f = f, c
                    if g > j:
                        g, j = j, g
                    if i > k:
                        i, k = k, i
                    if c > d:
                        c, d = d, c
                    if e > f:
                        e, f = f, e
                    if g > h:
                        g, h = h, g
                    if i > j:
                        i, j = j, i
                    if e > g:
                        e, g = g, e
                    if f > h:
                        f, h = h, f
                    if d > e:
                        d, e = e, d
                    if f > g:
                        f, g = g, f
                    if h > i:
                        h, i = i, h

                    return [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, k, l]
        else:
            if l < 15:
                if l == 13:
                    a = lst[0]
                    b = lst[1]
                    c = lst[2]
                    d = lst[3]
                    e = lst[4]
                    f = lst[5]
                    g = lst[6]
                    h = lst[7]
                    i = lst[8]
                    j = lst[9]
                    k = lst[10]
                    l = lst[11]
                    m = lst[12]
                    
                    if a > m:
                        a, m = m, a
                    if b > k:
                        b, k = k, b
                    if c > j:
                        c, j = j, c
                    if d > h:
                        d, h = h, d
                    if f > l:
                        f, l = l, f
                    if g > i:
                        g, i = i, g
                    if b > g:
                        b, g = g, b
                    if c > d:
                        c, d = d, c
                    if e > l:
                        e, l = l, e
                    if h > j:
                        h, j = j, h
                    if i > k:
                        i, k = k, i
                    if a > e:
                        a, e = e, a
                    if b > c:
                        b, c = c, b
                    if d > g:
                        d, g = g, d
                    if h > i:
                        h, i = i, h
                    if j > k:
                        j, k = k, j
                    if l > m:
                        l, m = m, l
                    if e > g:
                        e, g = g, e
                    if f > j:
                        f, j = j, f
                    if i > l:
                        i, l = l, i
                    if k > m:
                        k, m = m, k
                    if a > f:
                        a, f = f, a
                    if d > i:
                        d, i = i, d
                    if e > h:
                        e, h = h, e
                    if g > l:
                        g, l = l, g
                    if j > k:
                        j, k = k, j
                    if a > b:
                        a, b = b, a
                    if c > f:
                        c, f = f, c
                    if g > j:
                        g, j = j, g
                    if h > i:
                        h, i = i, h
                    if k > l:
                        k, l = l, k
                    if b > d:
                        b, d = d, b
                    if c > e:
                        c, e = e, c
                    if f > g:
                        f, g = g, f
                    if j > k:
                        j, k = k, j
                    if b > c:
                        b, c = c, b
                    if d > e:
                        d, e = e, d
                    if f > h:
                        f, h = h, f
                    if g > i:
                        g, i = i, g
                    if c > d:
                        c, d = d, c
                    if e > f:
                        e, f = f, e
                    if g > h:
                        g, h = h, g
                    if i > j:
                        i, j = j, i
                    if d > e:
                        d, e = e, d
                    if f > g:
                        f, g = g, f

                    return [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m]

                else:
                    a = lst[0]
                    b = lst[1]
                    c = lst[2]
                    d = lst[3]
                    e = lst[4]
                    f = lst[5]
                    g = lst[6]
                    h = lst[7]
                    i = lst[8]
                    j = lst[9]
                    k = lst[10]
                    l = lst[11]
                    m = lst[12]
                    n = lst[13]
                    
                    if a > g:
                        a, g = g, a
                    if b > l:
                        b, l = l, b
                    if c > m:
                        c, m = m, c
                    if d > k:
                        d, k = k, d
                    if e > f:
                        e, f = f, e
                    if h > n:
                        h, n = n, h
                    if i > j:
                        i, j = j, i
                    if b > c:
                        b, c = c, b
                    if d > h:
                        d, h = h, d
                    if e > i:
                        e, i = i, e
                    if f > j:
                        f, j = j, f
                    if g > k:
                        g, k = k, g
                    if l > m:
                        l, m = m, l
                    if a > e:
                        a, e = e, a
                    if b > d:
                        b, d = d, b
                    if f > g:
                        f, g = g, f
                    if h > i:
                        h, i = i, h
                    if j > n:
                        j, n = n, j
                    if k > m:
                        k, m = m, k
                    if a > b:
                        a, b = b, a
                    if c > j:
                        c, j = j, c
                    if d > h:
                        d, h = h, d
                    if e > l:
                        e, l = l, e
                    if g > k:
                        g, k = k, g
                    if m > n:
                        m, n = n, m
                    if c > f:
                        c, f = f, c
                    if e > h:
                        e, h = h, e
                    if g > j:
                        g, j = j, g
                    if i > l:
                        i, l = l, i
                    if b > c:
                        b, c = c, b
                    if d > e:
                        d, e = e, d
                    if g > h:
                        g, h = h, g
                    if j > k:
                        j, k = k, j
                    if l > m:
                        l, m = m, l
                    if b > d:
                        b, d = d, b
                    if c > e:
                        c, e = e, c
                    if f > g:
                        f, g = g, f
                    if h > i:
                        h, i = i, h
                    if j > l:
                        j, l = l, j
                    if k > m:
                        k, m = m, k
                    if c > d:
                        c, d = d, c
                    if e > h:
                        e, h = h, e
                    if g > j:
                        g, j = j, g
                    if k > l:
                        k, l = l, k
                    if e > f:
                        e, f = f, e
                    if g > h:
                        g, h = h, g
                    if i > j:
                        i, j = j, i
                    if d > e:
                        d, e = e, d
                    if f > g:
                        f, g = g, f
                    if h > i:
                        h, i = i, h
                    if j > k:
                        j, k = k, j

                    return [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n]

            else:
                if l == 15:
                    a = lst[0]
                    b = lst[1]
                    c = lst[2]
                    d = lst[3]
                    e = lst[4]
                    f = lst[5]
                    g = lst[6]
                    h = lst[7]
                    i = lst[8]
                    j = lst[9]
                    k = lst[10]
                    l = lst[11]
                    m = lst[12]
                    n = lst[13]
                    o = lst[14]
                    
                    if b > c:
                        b, c = c, b
                    if d > k:
                        d, k = k, d
                    if e > o:
                        e, o = o, e
                    if f > i:
                        f, i = i, f
                    if g > n:
                        g, n = n, g
                    if h > m:
                        h, m = m, h
                    if j > l:
                        j, l = l, j
                    if a > o:
                        a, o = o, a
                    if b > f:
                        b, f = f, b
                    if c > i:
                        c, i = i, c
                    if d > h:
                        d, h = h, d
                    if g > j:
                        g, j = j, g
                    if k > m:
                        k, m = m, k
                    if l > n:
                        l, n = n, l
                    if a > h:
                        a, h = h, a
                    if b > g:
                        b, g = g, b
                    if c > j:
                        c, j = j, c
                    if e > k:
                        e, k = k, e
                    if f > l:
                        f, l = l, f
                    if i > n:
                        i, n = n, i
                    if m > o:
                        m, o = o, m
                    if a > g:
                        a, g = g, a
                    if c > e:
                        c, e = e, c
                    if d > f:
                        d, f = f, d
                    if h > l:
                        h, l = l, h
                    if i > k:
                        i, k = k, i
                    if j > m:
                        j, m = m, j
                    if n > o:
                        n, o = o, n
                    if a > d:
                        a, d = d, a
                    if b > c:
                        b, c = c, b
                    if e > h:
                        e, h = h, e
                    if f > j:
                        f, j = j, f
                    if g > i:
                        g, i = i, g
                    if k > l:
                        k, l = l, k
                    if m > n:
                        m, n = n, m
                    if a > b:
                        a, b = b, a
                    if c > d:
                        c, d = d, c
                    if e > g:
                        e, g = g, e
                    if h > j:
                        h, j = j, h
                    if k > m:
                        k, m = m, k
                    if l > n:
                        l, n = n, l
                    if b > c:
                        b, c = c, b
                    if d > f:
                        d, f = f, d
                    if i > k:
                        i, k = k, i
                    if l > m:
                        l, m = m, l
                    if d > e:
                        d, e = e, d
                    if f > g:
                        f, g = g, f
                    if h > i:
                        h, i = i, h
                    if j > k:
                        j, k = k, j
                    if c > d:
                        c, d = d, c
                    if e > f:
                        e, f = f, e
                    if g > h:
                        g, h = h, g
                    if i > j:
                        i, j = j, i
                    if k > l:
                        k, l = l, k
                    if f > g:
                        f, g = g, f
                    if h > i:
                        h, i = i, h

                    return [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o]

                else:
                    a = lst[0]
                    b = lst[1]
                    c = lst[2]
                    d = lst[3]
                    e = lst[4]
                    f = lst[5]
                    g = lst[6]
                    h = lst[7]
                    i = lst[8]
                    j = lst[9]
                    k = lst[10]
                    l = lst[11]
                    m = lst[12]
                    n = lst[13]
                    o = lst[14]
                    p = lst[15]
                    
                    if a > n:
                        a, n = n, a
                    if b > m:
                        b, m = m, b
                    if c > p:
                        c, p = p, c
                    if d > o:
                        d, o = o, d
                    if e > i:
                        e, i = i, e
                    if f > g:
                        f, g = g, f
                    if h > l:
                        h, l = l, h
                    if j > k:
                        j, k = k, j
                    if a > f:
                        a, f = f, a
                    if b > h:
                        b, h = h, b
                    if c > j:
                        c, j = j, c
                    if d > e:
                        d, e = e, d
                    if g > n:
                        g, n = n, g
                    if i > o:
                        i, o = o, i
                    if k > p:
                        k, p = p, k
                    if l > m:
                        l, m = m, l
                    if a > b:
                        a, b = b, a
                    if c > d:
                        c, d = d, c
                    if e > f:
                        e, f = f, e
                    if g > i:
                        g, i = i, g
                    if h > j:
                        h, j = j, h
                    if k > l:
                        k, l = l, k
                    if m > n:
                        m, n = n, m
                    if o > p:
                        o, p = p, o
                    if a > c:
                        a, c = c, a
                    if b > d:
                        b, d = d, b
                    if e > k:
                        e, k = k, e
                    if f > l:
                        f, l = l, f
                    if g > h:
                        g, h = h, g
                    if i > j:
                        i, j = j, i
                    if m > o:
                        m, o = o, m
                    if n > p:
                        n, p = p, n
                    if b > c:
                        b, c = c, b
                    if d > m:
                        d, m = m, d
                    if e > g:
                        e, g = g, e
                    if f > h:
                        f, h = h, f
                    if i > k:
                        i, k = k, i
                    if j > l:
                        j, l = l, j
                    if n > o:
                        n, o = o, n
                    if b > e:
                        b, e = e, b
                    if c > g:
                        c, g = g, c
                    if f > i:
                        f, i = i, f
                    if h > k:
                        h, k = k, h
                    if j > n:
                        j, n = n, j
                    if l > o:
                        l, o = o, l
                    if c > e:
                        c, e = e, c
                    if d > g:
                        d, g = g, d
                    if j > m:
                        j, m = m, j
                    if l > n:
                        l, n = n, l
                    if d > f:
                        d, f = f, d
                    if g > i:
                        g, i = i, g
                    if h > j:
                        h, j = j, h
                    if k > m:
                        k, m = m, k
                    if d > e:
                        d, e = e, d
                    if f > g:
                        f, g = g, f
                    if h > i:
                        h, i = i, h
                    if j > k:
                        j, k = k, j
                    if l > m:
                        l, m = m, l
                    if g > h:
                        g, h = h, g
                    if i > j:
                        i, j = j, i

                    return [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p]

#and this is the quicksort algorithm!

def swiftsort(lst):
    l = len(lst)
    
    if l < 17:
        return sorting_network(lst)
    elif l < 128:
        a = lst[0]
        b = lst[l // 2]
        c = lst[-1]
        if a <= b <= c or c <= b <= a:
            split = b
        elif b <= c <= a or a <= c <= b:
            split = c
        else:
            split = a
    elif l < 8192:
        a = [lst[0], lst[l // 8], lst[2 * l // 8], lst[3 * l // 8], lst[4 * l // 8], lst[5 * l // 8], lst[6 * l // 8], lst[7 * l // 8], lst[-1]]
        split = sorting_network(lst)[4]
    else:
        a = [lst[0]]
        
        for x in range(1, 32):
            a.append(lst[x * l // 32])

        a.append(lst[-1])
        split = swiftsort(a)[16]


    lst1 = []
    lst2 = []
    mid = []

    for x in lst:
        if x < split:
            lst1.append(x)
        elif x == split:
            mid.append(x)
        else:
            lst2.append(x)

    return swiftsort(lst1) + mid + swiftsort(lst2)

#This is for testing the time of my algorithm.
length = 100000
runs = 60
test_list = [random.randint(1, length) for _ in range(length)]
t = 0

for _ in range(runs):
    start = time.time()
    sort = swiftsort(test_list)
    end = time.time()
    t += end - start

print(t / runs)
```

Comment: Python is not a good choice for benchmarking algorithms, since it is an interpretive language and slow. I would recommend C or C++ compiled with an optimizing compiler.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review@SE. `I have made a sorting algorithm…` I don't think so - you *tried* to implement quicksort, but left out base cases, for starters. Try `print(swiftsort(list('abramccarthybra')))`. (`…made a sorting algorithm in python` conventional wordings include *coded*, *implemented*, *crafted an implementation*.)

Comment: Ok, I have edited my title (is it better now?). Also, I have removed the insertion sort part because I wasn't using it anymore, and added the network sorting from 13-16. It should work now! I'll also try to add comments to the code.

EDIT: I've added a few comments to seperate my code out.

Comment: I do find the title much improved. Remaining issue with it: There's little need to repeat tags. `I have removed the insertion sort part` funny - I thought the "almost median of 32" uses it.

Comment: I've changed the insertion sort part to my quicksort algorithm itself because it was faster. Also, I've edited my post.

Comment: `[quicksort] in Java, C or C++ which I can't really compare` You could start with [Python implementations of quicksort reviewed here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quick-sort+python) - none of which seem to try and use a cheaper algorithm for short sequences.

Comment: `Note that python's time is not 100% accurate` Note that a time accurate to a fraction of a single clock cycle would give different results for multiple runs even with identical starting conditions: multitasking&memory hierarchy, dynamic clock multiplier selection, …. Some of which even apply to *core clock cycles* instead of pico-seconds.

Comment: [Morwenn](https://stackexchange.com/users/1446461/morwenn?tab=accounts) on [Optimal fixed-size sequential sorting](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/299059)

Comment: Are you judging your code against a library "sort"?  Don't.  Python is an "interpreted" language.  It might be 20 times as slow as the equivalent "compiled" code.  So you start 20x behind.

Comment: Count the number of times you compare two items.  If it is no more than N*logN, you are doing as good as a library sort algorithm.  If you are taking N*N compare, it's not good.  (OK, Quicksort varies between N and N*N, but those extremes come from abnormal cases, such as being in reverse order to start with.)

Comment: Yes, I know python is an interpretative language, while python’s sorted() is in C and it starts with a magnitude of speed of advantage. Also, I try my best to choose good pivots so that it is virtually impossible to approach O(N^2).

Comment: For a pretty recent & thorough discussion, see *Edelkamp, Stefan; Weiß, Armin; Wild, Sebastian*: "QuickXsort – A Fast Sorting Scheme in Theory and Practice"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This begins with opinions about the way the *partition&network sort* presented by [Sola Sky](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/239448/sola-sky) is coded.
I intend to get to comments on resource requirements - don't hold your breath.)

In your question, you provide context: the *what & why*.
Do so *in the code*! Python has got it right providing [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring), a documentation mechanism succeeding in making it unlikely for code to be separated from its documentation. (It even is available for *introspection*.) You may find yourself wanting to rename `sorting_network()` after writing its docstring.
Docstrings feature in the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#introduction), which you seem aware of.
It contains good advice such as *comments are unnecessary and in fact distracting if they state the obvious* -
`#importing` is a non-comment.
`math` currently is not used.
(`random` and `time` are "just" used in the benchmark - more on this later.)

`sorting_network(lst)`:
I notice you do not use [Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#abstract).
In the "decision tree", there is no need for an `else` following a `return`. One advantage of doing without is less code indentation.
I'd have liked to read, in the code, about the type of comparison network your generator constructs - I didn't try to figure it out, no comment on using networks of optimal depth or comparators(/comparisons?) here. My IDE "counts" 60 for len 16 - best known I find.

(`and this is the quicksort algorithm!` To split a hair, I expect *quicksort* to sort *in-place* (and, hopefully, with additional space dominated by the size of input). I'd use *partition sort*.)
`swiftsort(lst):`
`return`-`else`, again
"Habitually", quicksort is coded with *pivot selection* and *partition* factored out.
The "between-comparisons" are very readable -
`split = b if a <= b == b <= c else c if b <= c == c <= a else a` repeats one comparison instead of potentially four.
Prefer a `for` in comprehensions over enumerating the elements or appending them in a loop:
`[lst[l_ * i // 8] for i in range(9) for l_ in (l - 1,)]`
(The second `for` just introduces `l_` (=`l`-1) "in-line")
"The 8192-limit" looks somewhat arbitrary - how about using one item less than the number of bits in `l`s representation?

```
    samples = (int.bit_length(l) // 2) * 2 - 1
    samples = [lst[(l - 1) * i // (samples - 1)] for i in range(samples)]
    pivot = sorted(samples)[len(samples)//2]
```

(I could write `(int.bit_length(l)&~1)` - can I read it? You? The maintenance programmer?) (For no more than 16 items, `swiftsort()`/`sorting_network()` look advantageous. Not so sure immediately above.)
(Oh, look, you could do away with "the 128 comparison", too.)

While `lst` is a so-so name to begin with, `lst1`/`lst2` just don't do: I'd prefer `before`&`after` over `preceding`&`following` for brevity, and over `smaller`/`bigger` for not interpreting the order (which you may want redefinable via mechanisms like an optional comparator or a `reverse` flag like [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)).
In languages providing a shorter syntax for this, I might prefer the equivalent of
`(before if x < split else mid if x == split else after).append(x)` to stress the difference is in picking the sequence, not in the operation on it or the parameter.
In a "production strength sort", I'd try to avoid worst case resource consumption: recurse on the shorter of `before`&`after`, iterate on the other. Doesn't look any simpler with three-way partition.

With Python code in files, there are named *modules*: the module name is the file name "without the trailing *.py*". The module a python interpreter is started to execute has the name `"__main__"` during execution. This allows keeping short tests or benchmarks in code intended to be used library style:

```
# This is for testing the time of my algorithm.
if __name__== '__main__':
    import random  # place "non-library imports" here
    # some test code
```

Assessing resource usage to expect in general and timing, micro-benchmarking in particular are interesting cans of worms.
Let me just mention [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) and [Cython](https://cython.org/).
And that the bigger of the problem sizes you chose fits into (L3) cache of contemporary general purpose processors.

Comment: The more I think about it, the less I like `swiftsort()` to use additional lists instead of sorting in-place.

Comment: Ok, thanks! The reason I didn't do in place was because it was harder to code the partitions, and it was almost 2x slower. However, that might be because I'm a beginner coder. If you could help me write quicksort inplace without affecting the speed heavily, I would appreciate it a lot. Also, I'd definitely change the partitions to the bit_length suggestion you made. I'd try to make better variable names, type hints and more. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The main pretext I have for not doing so is that when you are doing three-way partition anyway, you may as well go dual pivot. (Not true by a mile ordering unique values, but then you'd know `len(mid)` at the outset of *partition*.) I'd be tempted even more if I could adapt the ordering network code generator too: that would need to generate code ordering in-place, too. Note that posting on SE puts contents under Creative Commons.